# Real time individual updates from MSSQL to web frontend

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core, signalr, service-broker

Looking for advice. We are working on a project with a requirement to provide realtime SQL updates to a web page.

Database is MSSQL, data can be updated from an array of different locations
SQL to retrieve info per room (box) contains joins

Code is .net core.

The required display is:-

[image]

Based on the image, there could potentially be any number of boxes (rooms). Each box is self contained and so unique info is displayed inside the box (room).

When any of the items in the box is updated within the database, that box is automatically updated on screen. (not the whole page)

We have tried signalR with SQL dependency,  however, this only seems to work for 1 column and 1 table ie. when the SQL contains no joins.

```
public async Task<string>  SendNotification() {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
          
            string query = "select [BroadcastMessage] from [Broadcast] b inner join Products p on p.BroadcastId = b.BroadcastId where p.BroadcastId = 1";
            using (SqlCommand  command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;
                DataTable dt = new  DataTable();
                SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                    dependency.OnChange += new
      OnChangeEventHandler(Dependency_OnChange1);

                   // dependency.OnChange += Dependency_OnChange1;
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    broadcastmessage = dt.Rows[0]["BroadcastMessage"].ToString();
                }
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
        return await context.Clients.All.ReceiveNotification(broadcastmessage);
    }
```

Are there any further recommendations / advice to achieve this?

Comment: You may want to consider Server-Sent Events.    Take a peek at some alternatives  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/5-ways-to-build-real-time-apps-with-javascript-5f4d8fe259f7/

Comment: Maybe use the dependency.OnChange occurance as a trigger to call another function for that room (parameter possibly) that runs the "join" queries and broadcasting.